# Why is my code not scraping the data I need?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web-scraping

I am trying to webscrape to check for availability of the Steam Deck Refurbished, however my program is not reading or storing the relevant data correctly from the CSS elements.

```
//This is a program to check the stock of the steam deck

//Packages
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
require('dotenv').config();
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const mySMS = process.env.MY_SMS;
const twilioSMS = process.env.TWILIO_SMS;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

const url = 'https://store.steampowered.com/sale/steamdeckrefurbished';

const product = {
    size64: '',
    stock64: '',
    size256: '',
    stock256: '',
    size512: '',
    stock512: '',
    link: '',
};

//Set interval
const handle = setInterval(scrape, 300000);

/*
This function scrapes the Steam website for the stock info of each Steam Deck size.
It fetches all the stock data before calling the SMS function if it's in stock.
*/
async function scrape() {
    //Fetch all the html data with Puppeteer
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: 'new',
    });
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    await page.goto(url, { timeout: 0 }, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
    const html = await page.content();
    await browser.close();

    //Load the html with Cheerio so we can use it
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);

    //Narrow down the html to smaller sections (containers)
    //Fetch each div box containing a Steam Deck size
    const container64 = $(
        'div.salepurchaseonlydisplay_PurchaseOnlyCtn_4-0sk'
    ).get(0);
    const container256 = $(
        'div.salepurchaseonlydisplay_PurchaseOnlyCtn_4-0sk'
    ).get(1);
    const container512 = $(
        'div.salepurchaseonlydisplay_PurchaseOnlyCtn_4-0sk'
    ).get(2);

    const containers = [container64, container256, container512];

    /*
    This function fetches the size and stock info from each container. It assigns each value
    in the product object.
    */
    function fetchData(value) {
        //Fetch the size
        const size = $(value)
            .find(
                'div.salepurchaseonlydisplay_Name_2K2zo'
            )
            .text();
            console.log('Size:', size);

    // Check for the presence of the in-stock and out-of-stock elements

    var stock = $(value)
        .find(
            'div.addtocartbutton_ActionOutOfStock_I_6Pn.CartBtn'
        )
        .text();
    console.log("Out of stock:", stock);

    if (stock == '') {
        stock = $(value)
            .find('div.addtocartbutton_Action_2ECxA.CartBtn')
            .text();
    }
    console.log("In stock", stock);     

    //Assign values to product object
    if (size == 'Steam Deck 64 GB - Valve Certified Refurbished') {
        product.size64 = size;
        product.stock64 = stock;
    } else if (size == 'Steam Deck 256 GB - Valve Certified Refurbished') {
        product.size256 = size;
        product.stock256 = stock;
    } else if (size == 'Steam Deck 512 GB - Valve Certified Refurbished') {
        product.size512 = size;
        product.stock512 = stock;
    }
}

product.link = url;

containers.forEach(fetchData);


    //If it's in stock, send SMS
    if ((product.size64 == 'Steam Deck 64 GB - Valve Certified Refurbished' && product.stock64 == 'Add to cart') || (product.size64 == 'Steam Deck 256 GB - Valve Certified Refurbished' && product.stock256 == 'Add to cart') || (product.size512 == 'Steam Deck 512 GB - Valve Certified Refurbished' && product.stock512 == 'Add to cart')) {
        SMS();
    } else {
        //console.log(product);
        console.log(
            'Current stock:\n' +
                product.size64 +
                ' - ' +
                product.stock64 +
                '\n' +
                product.size256 +
                ' - ' +
                product.stock256 +
                '\n' +
                product.size512 +
                ' - ' +
                product.stock512 +
                '\n\nNext check in 5 minutes\n'
        );
        console.log(product.stock512);
    }
}

/*
This function sends an SMS via Twillio
*/
function SMS() {
    client.messages
        .create({
            body: ` \n\nIT'S IN STOCK\n\n ${product.link}`,
            from: twilioSMS,
            to: mySMS,
        })
        .then((message) => {
            console.log(product);
            console.log(message);
            clearInterval(handle);
        });
}

scrape();
```

If out of stock, div.addtocartbutton_ActionOutOfStock_I_6Pn.CartBtn should appear within the container and the text should read "Out of stock". If it is in stock, div.addtocartbutton_Action_2ECxA.CartBtn should appear within the container and the text inside the button should read "Add to cart". If it reads "Add to cart", the program should then send me an SMS telling me the item is in stock, however the program is not reading any values for stock or size in the console log.

Comment: The issue could be in many, many places. Have you manually checked that `html` actually contains the content you are expecting? Also, classes ending with something like `2ECxA` sound very much generated - are you sure it's always the same identifier?  Also, please fix the indentation, it will be much easier to see the structure of the code if you do :)